# Integration with assortative matching function

Tags: integration, random-variables

Say two random variables $g$ and $k$, which are lognormally distributed with variances of logarithms $\sigma_{g}^{2}$ and $\sigma_{k}^{2}$. And there is a positive assortative matching function $k(g)$ that maps each $g$ with each $k$ for top to bottom, i.e. $1-G(g)=1-K(k(g)) \ \forall g$, where $G$ and $K$ are the cdf of $g$ and $\mathrm{k}$ respectively.

Then I want to integrate a function of $g$: $$\alpha g^{\alpha-1} k(g)^{\beta}$$. The answer seems to be $A g^{\left(\alpha \sigma_{g}+\beta \sigma_{k}\right) / \sigma_{g}}+C$, where $A$ is a constant and $C$ is the constant from the integration. How can I derive this integration result?

Comment: 'Positive assortatice matching' any reference on what is that?

Comment: @Thomas It is a function $k(g)$ such that $1-G(g) =1-K(k(g))$, where $G$ and $K$ are the cdf of g and k respectively. It turns out $k(g)$ constructed in this way will maximize the sum of $h=g^\alpha k^\beta$ over the distribution given $h$ is supermodular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on the c.d.f. reads:

$$G(g)=K(k(g)) \ [1]$$

suppose as an example $log \ G \sim N(0,\sigma_g^2)$ and $log \ K \sim N(0,\sigma_k^2)$. Than from the explicit expression of the c.d.f. of a log normal distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
condition [1] reads:

$$\frac{\log g}{\sigma_g}=\frac{\log k(g)}{\sigma_k}$$

And from here one has:

$$k(g)=g^{\frac{\sigma_k}{\sigma_g}} [2]$$

And now the integration is obvious. If the normal distributions have mean different from zero than a multiplicative constant in [2] appears, but everything remains otherwise equal.